# Can I catch an Exception of a type passed in by generic parameter in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, exception

Take this code for example - I think that when a TException is shown, I should be able to "catch" it and retry my `func()` an appropriate number of times. But when I put this code in the wild, even though an exception of type TException is thrown, it skips the catch clause and gets bubbled up. Can someone explain why?

```
public static T TryNTimes<T, TException>(Func<T> func, int times) where TException : Exception
{
    if (times <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException($"TryNTimes: `times` must be a positive integer. You passed in: {times}");

    while (times > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (TException)
        {
            if (--times <= 0)
                throw;
        }
    }

    // should never reach here
    return default(T);
}
```

Code is being called like this:

```
await RetryUtils.TryNTimes<Task, MyCustomException>(
        () => TryHandleElasticMappingError(dataGridResults, dataGridRecords),
        MyFieldsCount)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Any chance it's an async-ness issue? The above line is wrapped in a Try-Catch which catches an `Exception` where I'm able to verify the type of the Exception is `MyCustomException`. I can confirm that the inner catch block (the one in the retry method) is never hit.

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint within that `catch` block that doesn't get hit?

Comment: @krillgar yep it gets skipped

Comment: For giggles, try making it `catch (TException ex)`. I know I've done that before. Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: Running your code the exception gets caught, so you're not in fact throwing that exception in the delegate, if the catch block isn't running, or the catch block is in fact running.

Comment: @krillgar .NET Standard. I can give that a shot.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure what you mean. The exception is definitely being thrown because it gets bubbled up and I can catch it further up the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just exceed the `times` attempts? I fired this up in linqpad and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @khalid13 Then it was thrown `times` times, resulting in the catch block re-throwing the exception.

Comment: When I debug through it, it loops `times` times and then rethrows. So it works unchanged here.

Comment: Using your code, i'm not able to reproduce the issue; it goes inside the catch and executes the logic inside. How are you calling the function?

Comment: I don't understand how this code could possibly work the way you expect it to.  You `throw` in the catch block which will bubble until the next containing `catch` which isn't in this function.

Comment: Your code appears to work for me. Could you add how you're calling your code? FWIW, I'm calling it like this `int num = TryNTimes<int, ArgumentException>(() => throw new ArgumentException(), 5);`

Comment: Added in how I'm calling the code

Comment: is `TryHandleElasticMappingError` async?

Comment: @nick yessir `private async Task TryHandleElasticMappingError(...)`

Comment: Async and try/catch can be a little surprising in how it works. It's just the creation of the task that's in the try catch and that doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by the fact that your `func` is async. I would try something like this for async `func`s

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GenericException
{

    public static class FuncHelpers
    {
        public static async Task<T> TryNTimesAsync<T,TException>(this Func<Task<T>> func, int n) where TException : Exception
        {
            while(n --> 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    return await func();
                }
                catch(TException)
                {
                    if(n < 0)
                        throw;
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }

        public static async Task TryNTimesAsync<TException>(this Func<Task> func, int n) where TException : Exception
        {
            while(n --> 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    await func();
                }
                catch(TException)
                {
                    if(n <= 0) throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public static T TryNTimes<T,TException>(this Func<T> func, int n) where TException : Exception
        {
            while(n --> 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    return func();
                }
                catch(TException)
                {
                    if(n <= 0) throw;
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static Task AddTwoNumbersAsync(int num1, int num2)
        {
            var task = new Task(() =>
            {
                if(num1 % 2 == 0) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(num1)} must be odd");
                Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}");
            });
            task.Start();
            return task;
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<Task> addTask = () => AddTwoNumbersAsync(2, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("trying to add non async");
            var taskResult = addTask.TryNTimes<Task, ArgumentException>(5);
            Console.WriteLine("trying to add async");
            try
            {
                await addTask.TryNTimesAsync<ArgumentException>(5);
            }
            catch(ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error trying to add async");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As to why it's not working as expected, I agree with @Hans Kilian.

Basically, your `func` is returning a `Task`, or a promise to do something. That thing hasn't necessarily completed running by the time that `Task` is completed. The reason you would catch your exception outside of this method is when you're calling `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, you're waiting for that `Task` to complete, so it would throw its exception.

Edit: Full sample code, including async runner for just `Task` vs `Task<T>`

Comment: I seee I think that makes sense. Just one question about your modification - would this also work with async methods that only return Task, as opposed to Task<T>?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a sample (using extension methods) that includes an async runner for `Task` as well as `Task<T>`. Also included a quick sample to prove that non async will not work while async will.

Comment: Threw you a check; thanks for the clean and thorough explanation! I wish there was a way to coalesce the two methods (for Task and Task<T>) into one, but I guess this is good enough. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6):

> Any chance it's an async-ness issue?

As noted in the other answer, yes, it is an async issue.

Async and iterator blocks in C# are *coroutines*.  A normal routine can do three things:  run to completion, throw, or go into an infinite loop.  A coroutine can do a fourth thing: *suspend, to be resumed later*.  An `await` is a point in an async block where a suspension happens; it's `yield return` in an iterator block.

In your case the throw doesn't happen until the coroutine resumes, at which point the `try` is no longer in effect; the method with the `try` *ran to completion* because it is *not* a coroutine. If you want the `try` to be in effect then *the try has to be in an async block also*, and you have to `await` inside the try.

Similarly if you wrote:

```
IEnumerable<int> Weird(bool b)
{
  if (b) throw new Exception();
  yield return 1;
}

...
IEnumerable<int> x = null;
try
{
  x = Weird(true); // Should throw, right?
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // Nope; this is unreachable
}
foreach(int y in x) // the throw happens here!
```

An iterator block coroutine *begins suspended*, and does not resume until `MoveNext` is called on the iterator; all it does is return an iterator.  An async block coroutine suspends *on an await*, but is not *required* to suspend on an await; an await of an already-completed task is permitted to skip the suspension.

try-catch with coroutines is tricky; be careful!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed, technical explanation!